# Write $\sin[2\tan^{-1} (x)]$ as an algebraic expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to write $\sin[2\tan^{-1} (x)]$ as an algebraic expression. Unfortunately, I have no idea what my textbook even really means by "algebraic expression".

The stated answer is $\frac{2x}{1 + x^2}$

What are the steps to solve this sort of problem?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\arctan x = \theta$.  Then $\theta$ is the unique angle in the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $\tan\theta = x$.  Use the identity 
$$\sin(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta}$$
to obtain the result.

Comment: I know that $\tan 2\theta = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1 - tan^2\theta}$, and it seems like this is almost just switching $\tan 2\theta$ with $\sin 2\theta$, but I am confused why the denominator is different.

Comment: You are probably familiar with the identity $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$.  $$\frac{2\tan\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta} = \frac{2 \cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}} = \ldots$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand that $$\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{cos\theta}$$ but I'm not sure what you're trying to make me understand..

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the expression?

Comment: I don't know how to simplify trig functions.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2\theta$.  See what you get.

Comment: Oh! It becomes $\frac{2\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}$ which becomes $\frac{\sin 2\theta}{1}$ Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you should have obtained $\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta} = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{1} = \sin(2\theta)$.

Comment: I see I made some mistakes there. But, wouldn't $$(2 \cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} ) \cdot (\cos^2\theta) = 2\cos^2\theta \sin\theta$$ not, $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$?

Comment: Be careful.  You have to cancel a factor of $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Oh right, it becomes $\frac{2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}$ which equals, $\frac{2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}$.

Comment: Let me write out the details. \begin{align*} \frac{2\tan\theta}{1 + \tan^2\theta} & = \frac{2 \cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}\\ & = \frac{2 \cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}} \cdot \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\\ & = \frac{\frac{2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}\\ & = \frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta}\\ & = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{1}\\ & = \sin(2\theta) \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, that makes it a lot clearer. I still need work learning multiply fractions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think it always helps to draw a picture. Let $\theta = \arctan x$.

Then 
$-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Note that the sign of $x$ agrees with the sign of $\theta$, which agrees with the sign of $\sin \theta$.

Note that $\cos \theta > 0$ for all $x$.

So

\begin{align}
   \sin(2 \arctan x) 
   &= \sin(2 \theta) \\
   &= 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) \\
   &= \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}
\end{align}